# How do I get a European Union Pet Passport for my dog?

Tags: pets

I'm visiting Denmark with my Chihuahua soon, and have the US paperwork lined up (veterinary certificate from USDA APHIS).

Once I'm in Europe, how do I get an EU pet passport for my dog?

Specifically, will they generate a pet passport based on the documentation of my dog's rabies vaccine received in the United States, or will they require that the dog be vaccinated again?

Answer (score 4):

The process is reasonably simple: you just take your pet and [EU health certificate](https://www.aphis.usda.gov/aphis/pet-travel/by-country/eu/pettravel-denmark), the one you have endorsed by APHIS, to a veterinarian in the EU. Most vets can issue EU pet passports; just call and ask to be sure when you make your appointment. You have up to four months to do this, but if you plan to travel with your pet around the EU you should do it as soon as possible, as airlines and train operators will ask for the pet passport even for travel within the EU.

It is indeed possible that your pet might have to be vaccinated for rabies again.

A writer at The Points Guy recently [moved a pet to the EU and documented the process](https://thepointsguy.com/guide/european-union-pet-passport/). You may find it interesting additional reading.

Comment: Note that pet passport notwithstanding, some operators will not accept any pets (with the exception of assistance animals), including Eurostar, BA and EasyJet. Getting in or out of the UK with a pet is quite a challenge.

Comment: Traveling to the UK with a pet is apt to be easier by ferry, than it would be via Eurostar or airplane.

Comment: @David not sure if the UK still has the mandatory 6 month quarantine for pets entering the country...

Comment: No idea. I was commenting about travel, not about entry.